# Should the [details] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The SO tag [details](/questions/tagged/details) is overly broad and used by users for tagging all kind of questions. Probably it deserves a visit from Trogdor.

**EDIT**

As @Kara pointed out, *details* may refer also to [HTML5 `details` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element). To refer to such an element it would be better to define a new, specific tag (e.g. [html5-details](/questions/tagged/html5-details)) and let the others rest in peace.

Comment: It is used in a few cases to refer to [the html5 element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element).

Comment: @kara Thanks for the info! However I feel that in this case replacing those cases with a more specific tag would be better, say [html5-details].

Comment: Can you update your question with the contents of your comment re the html5-details, so it's up there loud and clear that those ones will get retagged?

Comment: @slugster Ok, editing done. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I could refer to the *Detail-Oriented programming pattern* but from what I've seen in questions form that tag, they aren't referring to that.